# Почему shell_exec возвращает null?

Tags: php, python, linux, время, exec

Есть `Python` скрипт. Через терминал все работает нормально.
При вызове из `PHP` функцией `shell_exec()` возвращает `null`. Владелец самого скрипта тотже что и на apache. Даже права расставил 077. При вызове других `Python` скриптов тоже все нормально работает.   В самом скрипте внутри есть задержка. Следственно думаю `shell_exec` тупо просто не ждет завершения этого скрипта для возвращения `output`. При том никакие ошибки не выводятся.

Comment: Ой, ну на самом деле это может быть вызвано разными причинами, как то: отсутствие терминала при вызове, недоступность интерпретатора в связи с запуском из песочницы, несоответствиями в переменных окружения...

Comment: Нет. Я уже нашел. Нужно было в команду в конец добавить & 2>1 или чтото подобное. Забыл уже. Но это исправило ситуацию

Comment: Первая же моя опция в перечислении именно об этом.

Comment: нашел: " 2>&1". после добавления этого внутрь exec() после моей команды PHP смог парсить output

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашел.
Нужно было во внутрь shel_exec() после самой команды добавить " 2>&1"

Comment: Потому что ваша программа пишет в stderr, когда PHP своим кривым взглядом его просто игнорирует.

Comment: что значит stderr? я думал все что выводится в терминале должно и вызываться при shell_exec... моя программа там на python несколько операций и обычный print